# Huwaei modem not working

Tags: usb, usb-modem

Yesterday I installed 12.10 in my Sony Vaio laptop. I have Huwaei E173 3G modem, I simply inserted that modem into USB slot, after a few seconds modem started blinking and activated. I opened network profile and created a new network under '**Mobile broadband**' tab everything was automated and I felt awesome, infact I used net for a while.

Next morning, I placed modem into USB, but nothing happened, no sign of modem presence even the modem is not blinking, I tried creating a new connection once again but attained no luck.

Kindly help me in resolving this problem.

Comment: Try typing this command lsusb in your terminal> You will see Huawei Technologies among others > It it shows that your modem is detected.

Answer (score 1):

The same happen to me .I was using a Huawei 3G modem. In my case i disabled networking and re-insert the modem and wait for sometime. After sometime i enabled networking and wait for few seconds. After few seconds i found the option for enabling mobile broadband. I choose the network connection profile which was listed . If you have enabled automatic connection your internet connection will started when you clicked Enable mobile broadband. Hope this works. Iam a complete newbie to Ubuntu . Just starting out few weeks before.

Answer (score 0):

First you must install huawei drivers for linux.By

1.Open the terminal and move to the directory where you extracted the huwaei datacard drivers for linux.
(`You must extract the drivers to the home directory`)

2.run `sudo chmod 777 install` command.

3.run `sudo ./install`
(This will install the drivers) and restart your pc .

After that your network manager applet will surely detect your modem or you have to manually create a broadband connection.